# Mysql Select shows result cut off first letter

Tags: mysql, wamp

I have the following purely mysql question. Some queries cut off the first letter. Never seen this before:

```
mysql> select distinct connect_town from ean_publiek where special_connection='1';

+--------------------------+
| connect_town             |
+--------------------------+
| ANDVOORT               2 |
| 'T LOO OLDEBROEK       8 |
| OUDSEND                8 |
+--------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)`
```

Now ANDVOORT should be ZANDVOORT and OUDSEND should be WOUDSEND, as can be seen from

```
mysql> select * from ean_publiek where Connect_Postcode='2042JE';

+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+------------------+--------------+------------------+----------------+---------------+------------+-------------------------------+
| Connect_EAN        | Connect_Streetname | Connect_HouseNumber | Connect_HouseRef | Connect_Town | Connect_Postcode | Market_Segment | NetOP_EAN     | NetOP_Name | Indication_Special_Connection |

| 871689294901618151 | Kerkstraat         |                   2 | E                | ZANDVOORT    | 2042JE           | 27             | 8716892720002 | Stedin NB  | 0
           |
| 871689294901618168 | Kerkstraat         |                   2 | F                | ZANDVOORT    | 2042JE           | 27             | 8716892720002 | Stedin NB  | 0
           |`
```

The mysql is from a wamp installation under windows 7, its about screen shows the following details:

```
WampServer Version 3.0.6 64bit Created by Romain Bourdon (2005) Maintainer / Upgrade to 2.5 by Herve Leclerc Upgrade to 3 by Otomatic (wampserver@otomatic.net) Multi styles for homepage by Jojaba Installer by Inno Setup: http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php Forum Wampserver: http://forum.wampserver.com/index.php
______________________ Versions used ______________________ Apache 2.4.23 - PHP 5.6.25 - MySQL 5.7.14 PHP 5.6.25 for CLI (Command-Line Interface)
```

the table has been created and loaded from a (very big) dmp file.

```
mysql> desc ean_publiek;
+-------------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                         | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Connect_EAN                   | char(18)        | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| Connect_Streetname            | char(24)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| Connect_HouseNumber           | int(5) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| Connect_HouseRef              | char(6)         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| Connect_Town                  | char(24)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| Connect_Postcode              | char(6)         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| Market_Segment                | char(3)         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| NetOP_EAN                     | char(13)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| NetOP_Name                    | char(24)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| Indication_Special_Connection | char(1)         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The question is of course, where can I set what so that the select distinct query shows the correct results? I found some reference on this forum concerning arabic texts, but this is dutch, not arabic. Other references were about missing rows, and this problem has to do with missing first letters, not first rows.

Thanks in advance!

@EDIT: trying to home in to the cause, it's not about the distinct: without 'distinct' same erroneous result:

```
    mysql> select connect_town from ean_publiek where indication_special_connection='1';
+--------------------------+
| connect_town             |
+--------------------------+
| ANDVOORT               2 |
| 'T LOO OLDEBROEK       8 |
| 'T LOO OLDEBROEK       8 |
| OUDSEND                8 |
| OUDSEND                8 |
+--------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Other attempt: the problem does seem not caused by the select 'specific field,' and the problem occurs on more than the city column, in the sample below the Connect_Postcode in the Netherlands always is of the form nnnnAB (4 digits 2 letters) and everything seems shifted, specifically the column 'Connect_HouseRef' seems to 'steal' the first character from the column to the right of it, and so on.

```
mysql> SELECT * from ean_publiek where Indication_special_connection='1';

| Connect_EAN        | Connect_Streetname | Connect_HouseNumber | Connect_HouseRef | Connect_Town             | Connect_Postcode | Market_Segment | NetOP_EAN     | NetOP_Name | Indication_Special_Connection |

| 871689294901618281 | Kerkstraat         |                  10 | BC   Z           | ANDVOORT               2 | 042JE2           | 7 8            | 716892720002S | tedin NB           0 | 1                             |
| 871687110001572501 | Vierschotenweg     |                  28 | B                | 'T LOO OLDEBROEK       8 | 095PR2           | 3 8            | 716871000002L | iander NB           0 | 1                             |
| 871687140022788551 | Vierschotenweg     |                  28 | B                | 'T LOO OLDEBROEK       8 | 095PR2           | 7 8            | 716871000002L | iander NB           0 | 1                             |
| 871687120000013011 | Iewal              |                  16 |  93 4W           | OUDSEND                8 | 551PT2           | 3 8            | 716871000002L | iander NB           0 | 1                             |
| 871687120000238476 | Midstrjitte        |                  30 |  93 4W           | OUDSEND                8 | 551PJ2           | 3 8            | 716871000002L | iander NB           0 | 1                             |
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> select distinct connect_town from ean_publiek where connect_town like '%andvoort';
+-----------------+
| connect_town    |
+-----------------+
| EEXTERZANDVOORT |
| ZANDVOORT       |
+-----------------+
2 rows in set (24.16 sec)


mysql> select distinct connect_town from ean_publiek where connect_town = 'zandvoort';
+--------------+
| connect_town |
+--------------+
| ZANDVOORT    |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select distinct connect_town from ean_publiek where connect_town like '%LOO OLDEBROEK';
+------------------+
| connect_town     |
+------------------+
| 'T LOO OLDEBROEK |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.09 sec)
```

I'm not making this up, and it's not a home study project. It's a project at job. I suspect it's some weird setting I have to set, it does not indicate non printable characters, it's an import from a dump file created by exporting from a test server.

Comment: That's strange. Are those results consistent? And if you left out the `distinct` (`select connect_town from ean_publiek where indication_special_connection='1';`) or the condition (`select distinct connect_town from ean_publiek;`) do you still get the missing front-end character?

Comment: worked out your suggestion, see edits in OP.

Comment: Is `'T LOO OLDEBROEK` actually correct? You haven't said anything about that one. Also try `select distinct connect_town from ean_publiek where connect_town = 'ZANDVOORT';` I know that looks odd, but I'm checking for non-printable characters. (But then, why would `select *...` work? Hm.) This should show `ZANDVOORT` or nothing I would think.

Comment: I've used mysql quite a bit and never seen this issue.

Comment: solved by using higher memory settings in my.ini (in old days called my.cnf). MySql does not complain, not one line in error log, which is an affront. You were just lucky until now I guess.

Answer (score 1):

solved by using higher memory settings in my.ini (in old days called my.cnf). MySql does not complain, not one line in error log, which is an affront. You were just lucky until now I guess. So, I was stupid, because I did assume (that wamp would magically always work), and assuming is wrong and it was lazy and I am sorry.